# Class 'Image' not found laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Using laravel 5.3

> FatalErrorException in UserProfileController.php line 26: 
>   Class 'Image' not found

I actually have added **use Image;**

```js
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Profile;

use App\Photo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Image;



class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function profile(){
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }
    public function update_avatar(Request $request){
        // Handle the user upload of avatar
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`composer require intervention/image`
 then  open the `config/app.php` file.

Add this to the `$providers` array.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Next add this to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

then `composer dump-autoload` and make sure you call it at the top of your controller : `use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;`

Comment: I am unable to solve this error after upload this code to production server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569242/controller-does-not-exist-found-error  You might be helpfull for me @Leo

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Installation
In this step you will have to configure intervention/image library in your application.

You will have to run below command in your terminal promt.

```
composer require intervention/image
```

Now i assume that you have successfully installed by above command.

OK, now i will configure service provider with their aliases name in following path config/app.php .

config/app.php
Add this service provider in provider array :

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

Now add facade to aliases array.

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

Comment: this is worked for me... i also followed your instruction into my production. thanks very much. @foram

Comment: @kinnariPrajapati your most welcome. Please do tick mark on this solution if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: i don't have enough reputation.. .when i gain it. .i ll sure come back and give your answer up mark. @foram